# Why does Mesa's image.c take so long to build 64-bit in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-c++

I am using Mesa-6.2.1 in my 3D graphics project, and it was initially a 32-bit solution in Visual Studio 2008. Now, I converted it to a 64-bit solution in VS2008. When I build in `Debug|x64`, the *image.c* takes a few minutes to build but when I build it in `Release|x64`, *image.c* takes a very, very long time to build. It takes almost more than an hour.

Looking closely in the image.c, I see that if I comment out the switch statement

```
switch (dstType) {
      case GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE:
         {....
[Line 127 and onwards]
```

in the following link: https://github.com/Starlink/mesa/blob/master/src/mesa/main/image.c, the build time seems to be quicker and resemble the time taken in `Debug|x64`.

I am not sure why this is the case. Since it is now in 64-bit version, is the pointer address space twice as big and so takes up more cache space? I would be thankful if someone could explain me the reason for this behavior in 64-bit.

Comment: Why such an incredibly old version of Mesa?  And Visual Studio for that matter.

Comment: @ genpfault I am working on an existing project and it was present there. But do you know the reason for this slow behaviour?

Comment: @Anna: If this was a C++ source file my first hunch would be tons of template instanciations. In one of my own projects there *used* (I managed to get rid of the madness a few weeks ago) to be a cartesian product over 5 dimensions of template parameters, each covering a set of between 5 to 10 elements. The resulting object file was, err, well, let's just say, that it wouldn't win any minimal size contests… \*cough\*. Still took only a minute or so to build. With templates ruled out, my guess is, that you're sending the optimizer on a wild scavenger hunt to find the shortest SSA path.

Comment: @datenwolf May you please elaborate?

Comment: @Anna: In C++ with templates it's very easy to send the compiler into a deep rabbit hole of instanciations; in fact C++ templates are turing complete, so it's perfectly possible to write **valid** C++ code, for which compilation will never come to an end. *This however is not the case here!* What I suspect to happen is, that the optimizing state of the compiler is confronted with huge number of possible data paths and tries each and every one to find the *single static assignment* (SSA) path with the least cost. Essentially it might be the traveling salesman problem.

Comment: @Anna: To rule that out you could try what happens if you disable compiler optimization.

Comment: @datenwolf I tried to disable optimization in Release mode, but I dont see any difference. While, in debug mode, it seems to compile in couple of minutes unlike in release where it takes hours!

Comment: I am using incredibuild to compile in debug and release modes. It takes 1min in debug mode and three hours in release mode for this specific file.

Comment: @Anna: I think we're past the point up until where reasonable guesstimates can be made. If the source file is valid C and the compiler eventually finishes the job then, as far as computer science is concerned, everything is fine [(cue "this is fine" meme here) ](http://i.imgur.com/c4jt321.png). To get deeper into the issue we'd have to profile the compiler execution on this particular source file. If this were a reasonable recent compiler, you could easily get the compiler group at Microsoft on the case. But VS2008 is legacy, so people won't bother.